# Full screen ads on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Hey guys, I've been looking at new ways to generate revenue from my iPhone apps, and have started to consider full screen ads. Do you guys know which networks provide them? I just recently read that full screen iAd only works on iPad, major bummer *thumbs down*

Answer (score 1):

You need iAd. It shows banners which can become full-screen ads when tapped. You probably agree that full-screen ads are pretty useless if they occupy all the screen all the time, the banner idea works well.

See [this iAd tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) for the process.

Comment: What I mean is in the arena of GreyStripe's full screen ads. They occupy the screen for a while at specific times (user clicks on a feature, etc), and they can dismiss it if they want. This is also available now on the iPad.

Comment: lol it's not that intrusive. And yes, I am going to have an ad free version =)

Comment: Four years later I have no idea what you're talking about.